# Following iOS Swift tutorial but receiving errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm following a video tutorial and I've followed the code exactly however I am receiving errors which the person in the tutorial did not receive.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  IMDb Search
//
//  Created by James on 29/05/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 James. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var titleLabel        : UILabel
@IBOutlet var releasedLabel     : UILabel
@IBOutlet var ratingLabel       : UILabel
@IBOutlet var plotLabel         : UILabel
@IBOutlet var posterImageView   : UIImageView


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    self.searchIMDb("King of Kong")
}

func searchIMDb(forContent: String)
{

    var spacelessString = forContent.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var urlPath - NSURL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=\(spacelessString)")

    var session - NSURLSessio.sharedSession()

    var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlPath) {

        data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error) {

            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var jsonError : NSError?

        var jsonResult - NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary<String, String>

        if (jsonError?) {

            println(jsonError!.localizedDescription)
        }

        self.titleLabel.text        = jsonResult["Title"]
        self.releasedLabel.text     = jsonResult["Released"]
        self.ratingLabel.text       = jsonResult["Rated"]
        self.plotLabel.text         = jsonResult["Plot"]
    }

    task.resume()

}

}
```

And here are the errors I am receiving.

[image: Error Messages]

NEW ERRORS SHOWING AFTER AMENDMENTS

[image: New Error]

NEW ERROR AT END

[image: New Error]

[image: New App Delegate Error]

NEW ERROR MESSAGE FIRST PAGE

[image]

Comment: for the IBOutlets just add "!" at the end

Comment: you should be using "=" instead of "-"

Comment: Like this? "@IBOutlet!" or like this "UILabel!"?

Comment: UILabel!   and UIImageView!

Comment: Awesome thank you! I made those changes and I'm still receiving one more error.

    var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlPath) {

Is giving me an error saying:

Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or "?"?

Comment: If you are sure NSURL it is not nil you can use "!" otherwise use if let

Comment: thank you sir, where does this go?

Comment: I have just added that in however it gives me 3 more errors now? Do you recognise these? (I have added to the original post)

Comment: If let error = error { ... }

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of the error at the error:

```
if let error = error {

    println(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

the json error try like this :

```
var jsonError : NSError?
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as [String:String] {
    self.titleLabel.text        = jsonResult["Title"]
    self.releasedLabel.text     = jsonResult["Released"]
    self.ratingLabel.text       = jsonResult["Rated"]
    self.plotLabel.text         = jsonResult["Plot"]
} else if let jsonError = jsonError {

        println(jsonError.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Which parts should be deleted and replaced with that code?

Comment: if you don't understand the code you should just ask otherwise next time you need to do it you will be posting another question here asking someone to fix the code for you again

Comment: Looking good! I just get a single error right at the bottom now saying "Expected Declaration"?

Comment: And I think I understand most of it just getting to grips with Swift and struggling a bit haha

Comment: which line does it occur? I have added a line var jsonError : NSError?

Comment: Right at the very bottom after the final "}"

Comment: Try closing the brackets.  }

Comment: Thanks man, I am receiving one more error message after that but its definitely looking better, this one is in the AppDelegate file. - have added screenshot above.

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {